# How to open a word document and find text in it without showing the document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

From the following code `TCN.docx` file had opened successfully using

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

instead of

`Visible:= False`

```
Sub workonTCN()
Dim odoc As Document
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\TCN.docx"

     Set odoc = Documents.Open(filename:=path)

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
     With Selection.Find
        .Text = "TI"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.COPY
Else
End If
    Windows("ROUGH").Activate
      odoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
      Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)
End sub
```

How do I apply range to find text without `Selection.Find`?

Comment: `application.screenupdating=false`?

Comment: `BUT find function do not work until i make TCN.Docx visible := true` Are you sure ? I think that should work.

Comment: but i need tcn.docx visible:=flase

Comment: Try to not use Selection.Find, instead declare Range and apply find on it. (not tried, but think that selection not working without visible, range can)

Comment: @findwindow screenupdating=false works thanks

Comment: @LubošSuk i have edited OP .. (how can i use range in above mention code?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Range.Find instead of Selection.Find:

1. Declare an object variable for the Range at the beginning of the Sub: `Dim rng As Word.Range`
2. Assign the range of the main story of the document to it: `Set rng = odoc.Content`
3. Substitute `rng` for `Selection` in the rest of your code (except for the last line that does the pasting)

Note that you may be able to remove the line for activating the Window where you want to paste the information.

Comment: i had done code but it has a problem with  `rng.MoveRight unit:=wdCell`

Comment: I believe you've received an answer to that in another Question thread you started, @ibneAshiq?